# html object css for resizing

Tags: html, css, resize

I need to resize pdf object (ie to make control in the lower right corner pulled by mouse)

It doesnt react on my line resize='both'.
What should i write in css?
Heres my code:

```
<object data='http://aspirant.beget.tech/upload/images/1.Pdf' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='100%' 
        height='100%'
        resize='both'>
<p>This browser does not support inline PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="upload/images/1.Pdf">Download PDF</a></p>
</object>
```

Comment: provide a full path for a pdf and make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: provided full path)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you wrap your object element to div [sample answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5wGv.png)